# OpenLayer3 - create vector layer with coordinates 0,0 to 1023,1023

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to have a vector layer with **16 tiles** - **4 by 4** and fill every tile with image.

I have problem with coordinates - as image is flat - I don’t know how to calculate them from `0,0` (top left corner) to for example `1023,1023` (bottom right corner)

This is first step to displaying images in hight-resolutions. I have also backend that can serve small pieces of image (almost 1 GiB total size), but I have problem with coordinates for each tile.

I’m appreciate for any suggestions how to split this task to few small steps.

Open Layer version: 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a tile vector layer - something that OL supports natively.  I wouldn't go managing the tiles myself, just use the inbuilt functions already provided.

Have a look at this example and see how the tile map server url is formatted.  You should be able to do something similar for yourself.

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/tile-vector.html

Comment: If I understood correctly, he wants to display image tiles. So there shouldn't be a need for a vector layer.

Answer (score 1):

I you have image tiles you don't need a vector layer. You don't manually have to calculate the coordinates of a tile, create a geometry for each tile and then load the image. This is not how it should work. :)

If you tell OpenLayers your [tiling schema/grid](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.tilegrid.TileGrid.html), it will automatically detect which tiles are required for the current view extent, load the tiles and display them at the right position. Take a look at the following examples, which show different techniques to use custom image tiles:

http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/xyz.html

http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/xyz-esri-4326-512.html

http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/xyz-retina.html